# Android, why actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); takes long time to hide title?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to display application logo instead of app icon and title.

I have an abstract activity with following method. Rest of my activities inherit this class.

```
public class AbstractActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set device orientation to portrait
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // setup actionbar
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

I can see logo of my app instantly however title will be display on right of logo for few seconds and remove after that which is horrible :(
Does something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was because of my "label" attribute of activity in manifest file.
I just removed the attribute from manifest and added logo attribute to "application" tag.

It's okay now.

```
<application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
            android:logo="@drawable/logo">

        <activity
                android:name="MainActivity"
                android:label="">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

...
```